# Preserving URL slug/vanity URL after EJS Form Submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, url, sails.js

I have a vanity url set as:

```
/Galaxy/3/3
```

The route for this url is:

```
/Galaxy/:x/:y
```

I have a form on this page which I would like to submit as a get method. I understand that by utilising a get I will always end up with the following URL:

```
/Galaxy?x=3&y=2
```

What I would like to know is, what is the best way to handle a form submit where I want to continue with my vanity URL. As of right now, performing the GET method on form submit results in the vanity url to be lost.

I am using EJS templates and Sails.js. Right now I can see 2 options myself:

1. Hijack the form submit event with JQuery and simply perform a window.location redirect utilising the form inputs and pushing them into a vanity get url.
2. Having an action in my controller which simply picks up the GET request and redirects it to my vanity url to preserve the set up.

Are there any methods that perform this in a much neater way?

Comment: Can you use post instead of get?

Comment: Hmm! In my routes I have 'GET /galaxy/:x/:y GalaxyController.galaxy I guess I can just do POST /galaxy/:x/:y as well and have POST/Get work the same route. Why did I not think of this :( maybe I did and it didn't work.. I'll get back to you

Comment: So I figured why I may not have gone that way. If my route is /galaxy/:x/:y, what should my form action be? Right now it is /galaxy to perform a simple get. But if I want to post + vanity url then the action would be?